# Can a Doppler shift of 3Hz be detected in a frequency of 1.2 GHz?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, high-frequency, telecommunications

Well! I am working on a project where i am supposed to detect a frequency shift of 3HZ in a carrier frequency of 1.2 GHz. My team has decided to bring down the frequency at about 100Hz or less where shift is detectable. Theoretically, a shift of 3Hz can be detected in 100Hz signal. However, in real life, will it be possible?

Comment: It's all about SNR and if noise is present then this is helped by the signal repeating and repeating. Theoretically yes.

Comment: How much time can you allow to make the measurement? Obviously, a change in 3 counts in a frequency counter that uses a gate time of 1 second is very measureable. However, if you need to make this determination on a shorter timescale, then the phase noise (short-term frequency error) of the signal and your reference will play a big role in whether this will be feasible.

Comment: 3 Hz in 1.2 GHz is 2.5 ppb, so you will probably need a rubidium frequency standard.

Comment: What is the system?  If it's something like a doppler radar where you have the original signal as a reference it is trivial by mixing the received signal with the transmitted signal. It's much more difficult if you have to do it without a reference.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on your frequency standard. 3Hz in 1.2GHz is not possible for cheap 10MHz standards, TCXOs even, but with a decent DOCXO or rubidium standard, it will be straightforward. The trick is not to try to count the frequency offset, but to compare your received phase with a reference. For a 3Hz difference, the comparison will spin a whole 3 times round in one second.

From 100Hz, it will be rather easier!

Comment: Well ! I am still a student , so my knowledge may not be that much. My team and I decided on using FM demodulation techniques to detect the change. We decided to mix the signal down to 100Hz where we can demodulate it. Has this method of demodulation any drawbacks?